# IWActivex, Intraweb, Delphi XE2-XE5. How to launch?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, intraweb

I'm trying to understand how to add Activex control to Intraweb stand-alone application.

I'm placing IWActivex control on unit1 form.

In field ClassID i'm writing the clsid of my registered OCX application. (f.e. C1A8AF28-1257-101B-8FB0-0020AF039CA3).
After lauching intraweb application i'm getting the error like "Unknown intraweb command "/$/C1A8AF28-1257-101B-8FB0-0020AF039CA3""
I was trying to google this error but it was unsuccessful.
Also i was trying to write ActiveXObject.Filename as 'C:\intaweb_test\mytest.ocx'
No results.
I was trying to learn manual by eBob [Manual](http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examinA1.htm)

but he is writing on Delphi 7 :(

Can anybody help me?

Thank You.

Comment: Did you look in the demo of intraweb? Demo Features > ActveXForm.pas

Comment: I'm sorry, but i cant find this demo in files dowloaded from eBob site. In Embarcadero Samples also.

Comment: Demo IntraWeb : http://www.atozed.com/intraweb/download/IntraWebDemos.EN.aspx

Comment: i missed this file when was searching for it :( During configuring IWActivex component i forgot to configure codebase parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an example in the demo Features.exe.
How to download the demo: http://www.atozed.com/intraweb/download/IntraWebDemos.EN.aspx

In the form ActiveXForm.pas there is a TIWActiveX component.

Set the Properties to

```
<TIWActiveX>.ClassID:= 'clsid:C1A8AF28-1257-101B-8FB0-0020AF039CA3';
<TIWActiveX>.CodeBase:= '/Files/mytest.ocx';
```